# ¿Como puedo almacenar un email para reutilizarlo en google apps script sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Al editar una celda quiero que se mande automáticamente un email a un correo ya almacenado. El flujo de trabajo que quiero lograr seria el siguiente: Lider edita una celda y automaticamente se envia un email a Colaborador. Colaborador luego va a tener que editar otra celda de la misma fila y automaticamente se va a enviar un email al correo de Lider. Este ida y vuelta sucede varias veces. Lo particular es que la primer celda editada tiene un menu desplegable con varios nombres de lideres para que se asignen, por lo tanto va a haber varios email asociados a los diferentes lideres que estan en ese menu y se tiene que usar el email del lider que es asignado en esa fila. Espero que se entienda!

Con mi codigo no logro que colaborador le mande el mensaje a lider. Es decir no puedo almacenar el email de lider para volver a reutilizarlo en ese ida y vuelta de emails. ACLARACION: siempre voy a usar el email de colaborador, ese no cambia.

Aca dejo parte de mi codigo:

````
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var value = e.value;

  // Automatización de notificaciones y correos electrónicos
  if (column === 11 && value === "Lo vio") { // Columna K (Onboarding)
    var leaderName = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue();
    var leaderEmail = getLeaderEmail(leaderName); // Captura el correo electrónico del líder asignado
    leaderEmails[row] = leaderEmail; // Almacena el correo electrónico en leaderEmails
    var setterName = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();
    var subject = "XXXXX";
    var message = setterName + " XXXXXX";
    sendEmailFromLeader(leaderEmail, subject, message);
} else if (column === 15 && value !== "") { // Columna O (Cliente Asignado)
    var collaboratorEmail = "XXXXX";
    var leaderEmail = leaderEmails[row]; // Utiliza el correo electrónico del líder almacenado
    var clientName = value;
    var subject = "XXXX";
    var message = "A " + setterName + " XXXX " + clientName + "XXXXXX" + clientName;
    sendEmailFromCollaborator(collaboratorEmail, leaderEmail, subject, message);
    
  } else if (column === 12 && value === "Lo vio") { // Columna L (Onboarding Cliente)
    var leaderName = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue();
    var leaderEmail = getLeaderEmail(leaderName);
    var collaboratorEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var setterName = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();
    var clientName = sheet.getRange(row, 15).getValue();
    var subject = "Programar reunión";
    var message = setterName + " XXXXXX";
    sendEmailFromLeader(collaboratorEmail, subject, message);
  }
}

// Resto del código de las funciones...

function sendEmailFromLeader(leaderEmail, subject, message) {
  var body = message;
  
  if (leaderEmail) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "XXXX",
      subject: subject,
      body: body,
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log("Correo electrónico del líder no encontrado.");
  }
}


function sendEmailFromCollaborator(collaboratorEmail, leaderEmail, subject, message) {
  var body = message;

  if (collaboratorEmail && leaderEmail && subject) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: leaderEmail, // Enviar al líder
      subject: subject,
      body: body,
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log("No se proporcionó el correo del colaborador, el correo del líder o el asunto del correo.");
  }
}

function getLeaderEmail(leaderName) {
  var leadersSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXXX"); // Nombre de la hoja 
  var leaderData = leadersSheet.getRange(1, 1, leadersSheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues(); // Rango de nombres y correos electrónicos

  for (var i = 0; i < leaderData.length; i++) {
    if (leaderData[i][0] === leaderName) {
      return leaderData[i][1]; // Retorna el correo electrónico del líder correspondiente
    }
  }
  return null; // Retorna null si no se encontró el correo electrónico del líder
  }```
````